# IBM Worklight - How to make Android environment code "independent" from the generated project?

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

When I build a Worklight project that also has the Android environment, a separate Android project is generated. That's fine.

If I add any files to the native folder of the Android environment which is residing in the Worklight project, those changes are getting replicated in the generated Android project. But, if I delete the generated project completely (for whatever reason), all the modifications that I've done in Worklight Android environment are lost (native folder is getting deleted).

Should that happen like that? Or is there any other approach have I to follow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When deleting the **generated** Android project make sure that you choose to **not** delete the project resources from disk.

Note that changes done in the native folder should be of specific nature, that is:

- change native resources (icons, images, ... for this we have the nativeResources folder)
- native code

Any other modifications should most probably be done in the common or android folders rather than the android\native folder.

Delete `androidtestTestappAndroid`
[image]

Make sure the `checkbox` is **not** ticked
[image]